# Outlook "skip" on reciving mail from 1 account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I added a Gmail account to outlook.for some reason when i do "send/receive" its send receive on 2 previous accounts, on the new account its only "sending".

is see like this:

```
account 1 sending. 
account 1 receiving.  
account 2 sending. 
account 2 receiving.    
account 3 sending.
```

in the settings its set correct to do send and receive.
what could be the reason that outlook "skips" receiving mail from the 3rd account?

Thanks

Comment: Ok. May be it is not showing (or may be i'm wrong). Can you send a test email from account 3 to account 3 itself - and see if this works?

Comment: its sent, but not received. (i know that its sent because o look in gmail)

Comment: is urs a POP or IMAP type?

Comment: IMAP. in the end it works. my mistake was that the wrong folder was set in "favorites". so i guess in imap it dosent show "receiving". its just does it.